# How to properly represent the authorship of someone's C-code used in my R package

Tags: r, package

I have a R package that uses Cubature codes obtained from http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/Cubature, which is written by Copyright (c) 2005-2013 Steven G. Johnson. (which is a great package, by the way) The CRAN Repository Policy (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html) says:

```
 The ownership of copyright and intellectual property rights of all components   
 of the package must be clear and unambiguous (including from the authors  
 specification in the DESCRIPTION file). Where code is copied (or derived) 
 from the work of others (including from R itself), care must be taken that 
 any copyright/license statements are preserved and authorship is not 
 misrepresented.
 Preferably, an ‘Authors@R’ would be used with ‘ctb’ roles for the authors of 
 such code. Alternatively, the ‘Author’ field should list these authors as 
 contributors.

 Where copyrights are held by an entity other than the package authors, this 
 should preferably be indicated via ‘cph’ roles in the ‘Authors@R’ field, or 
 using a ‘Copyright’ field (if necessary referring to an inst/COPYRIGHTS 
 file).
```

I have difficulties understanding the syntax Authors@R and how I am supposed to use ctb. My Description file has sections:

```
 Package: myRPackageName
 Type: Package
 Title: theTitleOfMyRpackage
 Version: 1.3
 Date: 2015-01-219
 Author: myLastName, InitialOfMyFirstName.
```

So am I supposed to instead say

```
 Author: myLastName, InitialOfMyFirstName. and @Johnson, S. G.  ctd
```

?

Comment: Are you using the `person()` object to specify your authors? There is a `role=` parameter for such objects. A "ctb" role is a "Contributor". More detail is given in the `?person` help page. Also see [this link from Hadley's R packages book](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html#author) for additional information.

Comment: Thank you for the useful link. I did not know that Authors@R now replace the Author and Maintainer sections, and it takes R code!